# force a link color style atrribute to follow default style when paste

Tags: html, css

The issue I have is that when I copy a piece of html, i.e., with

```
 <a>my link</a>
```

Then it will pick up the default style color on the page, which means, if I set  tag style color:#f2f2f2, then it will pick that up and use it after paste.

To solve this problem, I wonder if there is a way that I could set the color:none or somehow, into each  tag so that the color of the  will always be the default color for that tag (for example,  tag will be blue).

Let me clarify,
The reason I want to do this is that the piece of html text has default css color as red that is taken from a stylesheet, but after I paste it I do not want that style to be pasted , however, when I try that, it will, if I do that in certain phone devices. I was wondering if there is a way to set the style for specific tag to ONLY default color attribute value without modify it. For example, if default is blue for the other one, the font will change to blue not stay red.

HINT: Its especially obivously when you try to copy html into Google Mail Signature box.

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but if you want to change the link color:

```
a {
    color: red;
}
```

**Fiddle**: <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5G3BB/)</kbd>

---

For your edited question, if you want the default style, just do:

```
a {
    color: initial;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm also not sure what you mean, but to set a link color, use the css from Anonymous above.

You can also apply color properties to different states of links.

```
a:link {color:#FF0000;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link */
```

Be sure you set these styles in an external style sheet, do not use inline CSS.

In example:

```
<a style="color:#000;">This is Bad</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [CSS Keyword `initial`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#common-keywords)

> Initially CSS didn't provide a "default" keyword and the only way to
>   restore the default value of a property is to explicitly re-declare
>   that property.
>
> This has changed with CSS 2; the keyword initial is now a valid value
>   for a CSS property. It resets it to its default value, which is
>   defined in the CSS specification of the given property.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Common_CSS_Questions)

EG: `a.unstyled {color:initial;}`

However, in [my testing](http://jsfiddle.net/PJ7h8/) it seems that the browser's 'initial' value for a link is black not the blue we're all use to so you may be better off setting it explicitly.